Why dominant singular values represent main character of an image?
Do Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) to an image (for simplicity we use gray-levels images, the matrix is made with gray values of pixels) and delete some smaller singular values to get a new signal matrix named $\Sigma'$. Finally multiply $U$ and $V^T$ to get a new image. The new image is blurred but outline is OK. My questions are

Why bigger singular values represent main character of a image?

What's the relationship between the two methods generating a blurred image : SVD and DCT (discrete cosine transform)?



In order to illustrate what you mean (for the numerous people who don't know what this question is about) look at the front cover of this (very good) book. Taking a too small number of singular values gives the bottom image of the baby (please note the horizontal lines in the reconstruction). Taking more and more singular values yields increasingly better reconstructions...
